# why xml parsing in android

Tags: xml, android

why do we need xml parsing in android and which one is really better (SAX,DOM.PULL)

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure why you're asking "Why do we need XML parsing in Android?" since the question seems to answer itself: to parse XML data.  For example, there are many web services which return data in an XML format which will need to be parsed before you can use it in your application.

Here's an [article at Developer.com](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm) comparing the performance of the DOM, SAX and Pull parsers on Android.  It found the DOM parser to be by far the slowest, then the Pull parser and the SAX parser the fastest in their test.  [Here's another article at IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) that covers the three methods with sample code.

If you're going to be a doing a lot of parsing in your application it may be worth benchmarking the different options to see which works best for you.

Comment: thank u dave..can u tell me which is the default browser in android.does it have one or should it be integrated

Comment: Android comes with a Browser but to be honest I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: All three parsers - SAX, DOM, Pull - come with the Android SDK.  There isn't a default as such, just use the one which suits your requirements best.  The SAX and Pull parsers perform better and use less memory so it's probably best to go with one of those.  Have a look at code samples to see which one looks easier for you.